# CodeModule.ReplaceLine causes access to crash

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a function in VBA that replaces code on while the code is running. I am usign "CodeModule.ReplaceLine" to do this. this is primarily for the updating of a cookie in a web address. the function that is being updated is not running when the text line is being re-written. 
I initially used in in access 2013 but I now use 2016.

I suspect it's because the code is being changed after it has been compiled. but im not sure why there is a problem now and not before. the code is below.

```vb
Sub ReplaceCodeModuleText(sModule As String, sProcName As String, sFindWhat As String, sReplaceWith As String)
'FUNCTION:
'           Search the code module for specific text
'           Replace with new text
Dim VBProj As VBProject
Dim VBComp As VBComponent
Dim CodeMod As CodeModule
Dim Proc As Procedure

Dim SL As Long ' start line
Dim EL As Long ' end line
Dim SC As Long ' start column
Dim EC As Long ' end column
Dim sCodeLine As String
Dim vDummy As Variant

Dim Found As Boolean

    Set VBProj = Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject
    Set VBComp = VBProj.VBComponents(sModule)
    Set CodeMod = VBComp.CodeModule '    '.CodeModule

    With CodeMod
        SL = .ProcStartLine(sProcName, vbext_pk_Proc)
        EL = SL + .ProcCountLines(sProcName, vbext_pk_Proc) - 1
        SC = 1:        EC = 255

        Found = .Find(Target:=sFindWhat, StartLine:=SL, StartColumn:=SC, _
            EndLine:=EL, EndColumn:=EC, _
            wholeword:=True, MatchCase:=False, patternsearch:=False)

        If Found Then
            sCodeLine = CodeMod.Lines(SL, 1)
            sCodeLine = Replace(sCodeLine, sFindWhat, sReplaceWith, Compare:=vbTextCompare) 'not case sensitive = vbTextCompare
            Call .ReplaceLine(SL, sCodeLine)

            Debug.Print "Successfully Replaced: " & sFindWhat & " in VBA Module: " & sModule & " with : " & sReplaceWith
        Else
            Debug.Print "Did not find: " & sFindWhat;

        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Seems to me like an approach doomed to fail. Why don't you keep the cookie content in a variable?

Comment: I was kind of thinking that. I ended up writing to a table.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this question is old, and you never said what the exception was, however I was battling the issue of **.ReplaceLine OutOfMemory** exception for the past 2 days. So here is what worked for me in case someone else stumbles upon this cursed thread.

In my case, I was dealing with an **Excel workbook** with 100,000+ lines of VBA code in various code modules, such as worksheets, classes, modules, forms, etc.

I had to dispose of all the objects to clear memory, and then 'restart' or 'continue' the .ReplaceLine algorithm.

Here is some code that helps with clearing memory, etc.

```
' Declarations. Note: (filePath) is a full absolute file path
Dim xL As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
Dim wbk As Workbook = Nothing
wbk = xL.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

' Run algorithm Part 1 (i.e. replace lines in classes only)
Dim vbCodeModule As CodeModule
For Each vbc As VBComponent In wbk.VBProject.VBComponents
    vbCodeModule = vbc.CodeModule
    ' Rename all objects apart from forms.
    If vbCodeModule.Name.StartsWith("cls") Then
         ReplaceLinesFunction(vbCodeModule)
    End If
    vbCodeModule = Nothing
Next

' Save and close the workbook, close Excel and clear memory. This is to avoid OutOfMemory exception.
wbk.Save()
wbk.Close(False)

' Release and fully close the workbook
While (Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(wbk) > 0)
     Thread.Sleep(1000)
End While

' Release and fully quit Excel
While (Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xl.Workbooks) > 0)
     Thread.Sleep(1000)
End While
xl.Quit()

' Kill the Excel process just in case it didn't work. Try/Catch here as Excel might be disposed already. I have that in a separate function.
Dim id As Object = vbNull
GetWindowThreadProcessId(xl.Hwnd, id)
Process.GetProcessById(id).Kill()

wbk = Nothing
xL = Nothing
GC.Collect()
GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()

'Reinitialise objects
xL As New Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application
wbk = xL.Workbooks.Open(filePath)

' Run algorithm Part 2 (i.e. replace lines in modules only)
Dim vbCodeModule As CodeModule
For Each vbc As VBComponent In wbk.VBProject.VBComponents
    vbCodeModule = vbc.CodeModule
    ' Rename all objects apart from forms.
    If vbCodeModule.Name.StartsWith("mod") Then
         ReplaceLinesFunction(vbCodeModule)
    End If
    vbCodeModule = Nothing
Next
```

Comment: This is VB.Net, not VBA, so it doesn't really fit the question... but it is probably the closest match.